# How to use tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy with label smoothing in keras

Tags: tensorflow

I want to use label smoothing in keras model.fit, but it give error. 
If I try

```
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(label_smoothing=0.1))
```

It gives error

```
 TypeError: sigmoid_cross_entropy() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'multi_class_labels' and 'logits'
```

If i add

```
loss=tf.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred, label_smoothing=0.1))
```

It gives

```
NameError: name 'y_true' is not defined
```

How can i use this loss function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keras passes two parameters to its loss function. In order to use more, you can wrap any native TF function as custom function, pass needed parameters and pass it to Keras `model.fit`

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.compat.v1.losses.sigmoid_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred, label_smoothing=0.1)

model.compile(optimizer, loss=custom_loss)
```